# patternMismatch for input url in html

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I have a input url and pattern set to "^http://" as simplest pattern. When I use the value as below it says as patternMismatch in validity object. What is wrong with the pattern or value

```
<input value="http://www.example.com" pattern="^http://" type="url"/>,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslashes. Also, start and end anchoring is implicit:

```
<input value="http://www.example.com" pattern="http:\/\/.+" type="url"/>
```

The `.+` ending means that there must be at least one character. Basically, this RegExp is actually:

```
/^http:\/\/.+$/u
```

The `u` flag and `^` and `$` anchors are implicit:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input
- [Should I use ^ and $ in html5 input regex pattern validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142208/should-i-use-and-in-html5-input-regex-pattern-validation)