# Validators.pattern adding extra ^ and $ in the pattern

Tags: angular

I am using the Validators.pattern to check that the `name` filed in my form contains only letters. The pattern I have added is `lastName:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z]+')]]`. But I notice that in case there is an error, the error message contains extra `^` and `$`. Why? The code example is at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xesgxe

Add an invalid name (say `1`) in `Last Name` filed (not `First Name` as I am using a different validator for it.  You'll see the error `The required pattern is: ^[A-Za-z]+$`. Notice the extra `^` and `$` in the error string while the pattern was `[A-Za-z]+`

Check `createForm()` function in `signup-component.component.ts`. Look for line `lastName:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z]+')]]`

The error message comes from `ShowErrorsComponent`. Check `'pattern': (params) => 'The required pattern is: ' + params.requiredPattern` in `errorMessages` in the class `ShowErrorsComponent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how you make a regex pattern match the entire input (^ - stands for start of line and $ for end of line).

Otherwise your pattern `[A-Za-z]+` will find match in this string: `123a` so the validator will say the string is valid.

**EDIT**: Looking over the code (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L293), it seems to be possible to use the exact pattern you want, by passing a RegExp instead of a string:

`Validators.pattern(/[A-Za-z]+/)`

My guess is they added this behavior because the `pattern` attribute on the input works the same (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp).

See also: [Should I use ^ and $ in html5 input regex pattern validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142208/should-i-use-and-in-html5-input-regex-pattern-validation)

Comment: I get that but what confused me is that `Angular` added this by itself. Shouldn't `pattern` take the exact pattern specified?

Comment: @ManuChadha Updated my response

Comment: Many Thanks. I notice the code. I also looked at the documentation `https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator` which says that the directive `Follows pattern attribute semantics; i.e. regex must match entire Control value.` and that this directive is added when `html` code uses `pattern` attribute. It seems that by default `pattern` attribute in `html` matches against the entire value of the `input`. So to make this Directive compatibe with `html`'s behaviour, `^` and `$` are added. But this is all just my theory

Comment: This was a gotcha moment for me too. In my case, I have a list of strings supplied by the API with the pattern strings. How can I use those in the validator then (so that I don't get the starter and ender characters automatically? I see you suggest using regex instead but I have strings...